# "data-cycle-loader=wait" for "cycle2.js" not working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I've a bit of php code that selects 11 random images from a common folder, then displays them in a slide show using cycle2.js  This is used throughout the site and on different levels from the root directory.

My problem is this: No matter what I've tried, the 11 images load in a vertical stack then, collapse before the slide show begins. Otherwise, everything else works fine. I'm under the impression that "data-cycle-loader=wait" is supposed to do what I'm trying to achieve (pre-load) but doesn't seem to be working.

Here's a page stripped down to the elements in question:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Some Title</title>
        <meta name="description"
              content="Some Description" />
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    </head>
<body>
<div class="cycle-slideshow  data-cycle-loader=wait">
    <?php
        $images = array();
        $directory = $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] . '/images_carosel/';
        if ($handle = opendir($directory)) {
        while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle))) {
        if (preg_match("/\.png$/", $file)) $images[] = $file;
            elseif (preg_match("/\.jpg$/", $file)) $images[] = $file;
            elseif (preg_match("/\.jpeg$/", $file)) $images[] = $file;
            elseif (preg_match("/\.gif$/", $file)) $images[] = $file;
            }
        shuffle($images);
        closedir($handle);
        }
    ?>
    <?php
        for($i= 0; $i < 11; $i++) {
        echo '<img src="/images_carosel/'.$images[$i].'" alt="Some Description" title="Some Description" >';
        }
    ?>
</div>
<script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.cycle2.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: There is a typo in your code (missing quote). Change *<div class="cycle-slideshow  data-cycle-loader=wait">* to *<div class="cycle-slideshow"  data-cycle-loader="wait">*.

Comment: Thank you. I corrected the typo, however the problem persists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to do some research to find out your issue.

The problem is in the speed of your browser/pc. Because the images are loaded with PHP (server side). The html directly put them to the output. The cycle2 slider start working after the body loaded. This means you will see all your images for a short time. (depending on the speed of your browser/pc).

Solution: Only set one image with php and add the rest of your images later when the slider is running. I've created a code based on yours to for testing and it's working for me.

```
<?php

$firstImage = ''; // Store the first image we will echo with php
$imagesLink = array(); // array with <img.... strings

// Your old code
$images = array();
$directory = $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] . '/images_carosel/';
if($handle = opendir($directory)) {
    while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle))) {
        if(preg_match("/\.png$/", $file)) $images[] = $file;
        elseif(preg_match("/\.jpg$/", $file)) $images[] = $file;
        elseif(preg_match("/\.jpeg$/", $file)) $images[] = $file;
        elseif(preg_match("/\.gif$/", $file)) $images[] = $file;
    }
    shuffle($images);
    closedir($handle);
}
for($i= 0; $i < 11; $i++) {
    // No echo enymore but store them in the array
    array_push($imagesLink, '<img src="/images_carosel/'.$images[$i].'" alt="Some Description" title="Some Description" >');
}
$firstImage = $imagesLink[0]; // Get the first image from array
array_shift($imagesLink); // Remove this image from array te prevent double images
$comma_Images = implode(",", $imagesLink); // Convert everything to an string for casting to JS

?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Some Title</title>
        <meta name="description"
              content="Some Description" />
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />

        <script src="jquery311.js"></script>
        <script src="jquery.cycle2.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(function(){
                var img = '<?php echo $comma_Images; ?>'; // Get the php image strings
                var imgArr = img.split(","); // Convert to JS array
                for (var i=0; i < imgArr.length; i++) {
                    $('.cycle-slideshow').cycle('add', imgArr[i]); // Add them to the cycle
                }
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="cycle-slideshow" data-cycle-loader="wait">
        <?php 
            echo $firstImage; // add the first image by php so slider has something to init
        ?>
    </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

I hope for you that this will fix it for you. Good luck.

Comment: Paules... your solution worked like a charm, both locally and on the remote server. To keep Google's mobile-friendly test happy I did move the script you added to the bottom of the page (with my others) just before the closing body tag. It still worked perfectly. Thank you so much!